# Mysql Table corrupted after restarting PC

Tags: mysql, symfony, windows-7

I am working on `Symfony2` Project and am beginner in `symfony` Framework. I am using XAMPP as webserver. Everything is working properly until system restarts. When I restart my computer the tables of mysql database using by symfony project corrupts automatically.

I am using windows 7 professional 32bit OS.so, is there any problem in `mysql`?

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL tables can become corrupt for several reasons, such as hardware
>   failure, operating system bugs, viruses and bugs in MySQL. hMailServer
>   itself does not cause corrupt MySQL tables. hMailServer communicates
>   with MySQL over TCP/IP using a standardized language.

There's nothing in this language that can cause corrupt tables.

If a MySQL table becomes corrupt, you need to repair it. Note that repairing a corrupt MySQL table may lead to loss of data. It's therefore important to create a backup of your system.

How do you know whether a table is corrupt?

Examine the hMailServer error log. If you see a lot of Error while executing SQL statement-messages, then it's likely that one or more of your tables are corrupt. Feel free to ask in the forum if you're unsure.

**Step 1: Determine MySQL password**

If you are using an external version of MySQL, you should already know your MySQL password.
If you are using the built-in MySQL version that comes with hMailServer, you might not know your password. To determine it, follow these steps:

1. Run the script hMailServer/Addons/Utilities/DecryptBlowfish.vbs.
2. Enter your main hMailServer Administrator password. This is the
   password you specified during the installation when you first
   installed hMailServer. Click OK.
3. Open up hMailserver.ini, located in your Windows directory or
   hMailServer bin directory.
4. Copy the database password from hMailServer.ini to the "Enter
       encrypted password" dialog. In hMailServer.ini, you should see a
       line looking like this: [Database]
       ...
        password=c85dae3cb73394ab
       In this example, c85dae3cb73394ab is the encrypted password.
5. Click OK in DecryptBlowfish to view your password

DecryptBlowfish will now show your password. Either keep the dialog open or memorize the password.

**Step 2: Connect to the server**

To be able to repair your table, you need to connect to the MySQL server using a MySQL client. You can use SQLyog for this.

Download and install SQLyog

1. Create a new connection.
2. Enter the connection information for your MySQL server. If you are
   using the built-in server, you should enter hostname: localhost,
   user:root, password:password from DecryptBlowfish, port:3307
3. Click Connect to connect to the database server

**Step 3: Repair the table**

Follow these steps to run the SQL statement to repair the table.

1. In the tree to the left, click on the hmailserver database.
2. The hMailServer database will now be active.
3. In the right part of the SQLyog window, click on the Query tab.
   Enter REPAIR TABLE tablename, for example, REPAIR TABLE hm_messages.
4. Click on the Execute Current Query button in the toolbar (or select
   Edit->Execute Query->Execute current query or press F5).

MySQL should now repair the table. After the table has been repaired, restart the MySQL and than the hMailServer service. Depending on what table is corrupt, a restart of the services may not be required, but we recommend that you always do it.

[Source](http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=howto_repair_mysql)

Comment: Did you copy / paste this excerpt from somewhere? If so, please include the source and refrain from plagiarism.

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar But the tables corrupted that i have used in symfony project and another table remains as it is.so is there possible any bug in symfony project.?